# Find me if you can

Tags: riddle, word

1. I am a five letter word.
2. If  lost, I can help.
3. SCRAMBLED, you can put something in me.
4. Part of me divides people.
5. Part of me is contained in many games.
6. BACKWARDS, part of me appeals to many people and another part is used by many people.

What am I?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am a five letter word.

> Trace

If lost, I can help.

> Tracing can help find what is lost.

SCRAMBLED, you can put something in me.

> CRATE is an anagram of TRACE.

Part of me divides people.

> RACE can divide people.

Part of me is contained in many games.

> ACE is included in most card games.

BACKWARDS, part of me appeals to many people and another part is used by many people.

> From ECART, ART appeals to many people and CAR is used by many people.

What am I?

> Trace.